# DynamoDB expression not returning all the attributes

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

Using the following to get a scan result:

```
PaginatedScanList<Table> scanList =
                    dynamoDBMapper.scan(table.class, new DynamoDBScanExpression());
```

YAML

```
TableDDB:
    Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
    # Retain the DynamoDB table even if stack is deleted
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: "id"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "skill"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "locale"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: "id"
          KeyType: "HASH"
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      TableName: "table"
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: "skill-locale-index"
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: "skill"
              KeyType: HASH
            - AttributeName: "locale"
              KeyType: RANGE
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: "ALL"
```

The table record is as follows

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "table")
public class Table {
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
    @NonNull
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(
            attributeName = "skill",
            globalSecondaryIndexName = "skill-locale-index")
    private String skill;

    @DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(
            attributeName = "locale",
            globalSecondaryIndexName = "skill-locale-index")
    private String locale;
}
```

But the result that I am getting is only having id and skill in all the entries even though locale also exists. I want to return all the attributes in the structure above

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you add to your question post, the code referenced by `table.class`?  here is a an example if you don't have one already https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBTable

Comment: @petey added it

Comment: `private String locale;`  make this public and try?

Comment: others are also private only

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add the annotation reference for [DynamoDBAttribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBAttribute)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "table")
public class Table {
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
    @NonNull
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(
            attributeName = "skill",
            globalSecondaryIndexName = "skill-locale-index")
    private String skill;

    @DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(
            attributeName = "locale",
            globalSecondaryIndexName = "skill-locale-index")
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "locale")
    private String locale;

}
```

More info here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBAttribute